# Enable/Disable Conversational bot in MS Teams

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

How to enable and disable the conversational bot in MS Teams?

In our application, we have to enable the conversation bot in bot chat window:

[image]

I tried  `"isNotificationOnly": false` but it is not working.

Comment: Have you enabled the "Teams" channel in the "Channels" section for the bot in the Azure portal?

Comment: Yes i have enabled the "Teams" channel for the bot services in Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing your manifest after editing the value "isNotificationOnly": false.

Also could you please try with blocking/unblocking your bot conversation like below:

[image]

Comment: I tried this option, it is working fine.  Is there any option to enable for all the users?

Comment: @saraswathi, You can uninstall the app from your organization and re-install it. It might resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled and re-install the manifest file, but it is not working.

Comment: @saraswathi, After uninstalling and installing again it was working fine at our end. We checked in Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.29469. Please try to update your Teams client and check.